# rounding a decimal

Tags: .net, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Math.Round not keeping the trailing zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307630/math-round-not-keeping-the-trailing-zero)
>   [How to round double values but keep trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833284/how-to-round-double-values-but-keep-trailing-zeros)

I have a decimal that I want to round to 2 dp.  So, I have used Math.Round().  When I have a number like this

```
23.126
```

I get the format that I want

```
23.13
```

But when I have something like this

```
23
```

I get

```
23
```

What I'd like is to always get 2 dp.  So, in the previous example I'd like

```
23.00
```

If I have

```
23.1
```

I'd like

```
23.10
```

Any idea how I might do this?

Comment: If you declare a decimal with decimal places, it will be displayed with the same number of decimal places: `decimal d = 23.00m;`. http://ideone.com/NJRXUq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you don't want to round the value, you want to format it into a string.

```
string formatted = value.ToString("N2");
```